# Binding Value to Radio Button in Interface Builder does not trigger action linked to radio button

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm saving the value set by the user using a radio button with the `UserDefaults` class.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(radio_gif.state.rawValue, forKey: "gif")
```

The value is bound to the control by setting the bindings like below

[image]

The radio button State is set correctly but the action that is supposed to fire is not firing.

Comment: Show lines of code instead.

Comment: @ElTomato what lines of code ? It is done from the UI Builder see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33587089/848968

Comment: How did you check if the action is fired?

Comment: @Willeke By putting a breakpoint in the action method.

Comment: Is the action firing if the binding is removed? When do you do `UserDefaults.standard.set(radio_gif.state.rawValue, forKey: "gif")`?

Comment: @Willeke The action is firing always when the radio button is selected manually.But after saving the settings and reopening the application,the radio button change event is not firing.Since the radio button is set using the user preference, shouldn't this event fire?

Comment: No, the binding does not fire the action. The binding loads and saves the value.